# What happens if you write to `mmap`ed sparse file when disk is full?

Tags: posix, mmap

Many systems have `mmap` or equivalent functionality, where the contents of a file can be mapped to a memory address range.

Also many systems have sparse files, i.e. files with ranges of non-allocated blocks that takes no space, reads as zeros, and are allocated upon writing.

I want to know what happens when a mapping for a sparse region of a file is written, but the filesystem is full. Is the behavior specified in POSIX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html:

> An implementation may generate SIGBUS signals when a reference would cause an error in the mapped object, such as out-of-space condition.

And that's exactly what Linux does (specifically, with `si_code=BUS_ADRERR`).